# How to import Frontmatter & Markdown in JavaScript with Webpack

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, markdown

I am trying to incrementally build a React site with the content written in Markdown.

I am stuck so far as I am trying to import **a single Markdown file with Frontmatter** to render.

I have tried [front-matter-loader](https://github.com/elliottsj/front-matter-loader) and [raw-loader](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/raw-loader); both throw errors:

```
/pages/home.md: Invalid left-hand side in prefix operation (1:2)
1 | ---
  |   ^   
2 | title: This is the home page  
3 | ---
```

### Here is my simple JavaScript test:

```
import home from '../pages/home.md';

console.log('testing');
console.log(home);
```

### Here are my loaders in the webpack config:

```
...
module: {
    rules: [
        { 
            test: /\.(js)$/, 
            use: {
                loader: 'babel-loader',
                options: {
                    presets: ['env'],
                    cacheDirectory: '.babel_cache'
                }
            }
        },
        {
            test: /\.md$/,
            use: 'raw-loader'
        }
    ]
},
...
```

What I expected from using `raw-loader` was a string, which I could then pass to [front-matter](https://github.com/jxson/front-matter), extract, and then render HTML with [marked](https://github.com/chjj/marked).  However, I obviously cannot seem to `require`/`import` the file properly.  My next tests will be to remove the webpack loaders altogether and try to use node's `fs` to read the file.  I wondered if anyone would be able to help me spot any error here.

I keep thinking, the `front-matter-loader` is not a complicated file at all ([view here](https://github.com/elliottsj/front-matter-loader/blob/master/index.js)), and there's no reason why it shouldn't load the file.

Thanks for any insight.

Answer (score 2):

From reading the [front-matter-loader docs](https://github.com/elliottsj/front-matter-loader#usage), looks like you need to pass the results from `front-matter-loader` through a `json-loader` or extract the front-matter data and markdown separately. Assuming you've installed the `json-loader`, `front-matter-loader`, and `raw-loader` packages, the following might work.

Passing `front-matter-loader` results through `json-loader` in your webpack config:

```
    ...
    module: {
        rules: [
            ...
            {
                test: /\.md$/,
                use: ['json-loader', 'front-matter-loader']
            }
        ]
    },
    ...
```

Extracting the front-matter data and markdown separately:

```
var data = require('json!front-matter!../pages/home.md')
var content = require('raw!front-matter?onlyBody!../pages/home.md')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the front-matter module.

**Installation**

`npm install front-matter`

OR

`yarn add front-matter`

**Usage**

```
var fs = require('fs')
  , fm = require('front-matter')

fs.readFile('path/to/markdown-file.md', 'utf8', function(err, data){
  if (err) throw err

  var content = fm(data)

  console.log(content)
})
```